# Android AsyncTask Error [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()]

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to parse an xml file from a Url and get the Lat values in the file and just display them in a toast window for debugging. I'm getting this error: "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
public void getGpx(String area) {
   final String area2 = area;
    new GHAsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>() {
        protected List<String> saveDoInBackground(Void... params)
                throws Exception {
            String urlString = fileListURL + area2 + ".gpx";
            logUser(urlString);
            ArrayList testingXml = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("trkpt");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                    NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("lat");
                    Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
                    testingXml.add(line.getTextContent());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (SAXException e) {
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException a) {
            }
            return testingXml;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> gpxList) {
            if (hasError()) {
                getError().printStackTrace();
                logUser("Are you connected to the internet? Problem while fetching remote area list: "
                        + getErrorMessage());
                return;
            } else if (gpxList == null || gpxList.isEmpty()) {
                logUser("something went wrong");
                return;
            }

            logUser(gpxList.toString());

        }
    }.execute();


}
```

I'm hoping someone can help me fix this error. There might be other errors in the code, that I haven't found yet. Just a rookie trying to piece this together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything in UI thread from async task, probably some of your functions inside asynctask are calling UI Thread, you can call them onPreExecute, onPostExecute, or use publishProgress to call UI thread while asynctask is running.

Comment: I overlooked the logUser() at the top, this was calling a toast window. Thanks!